# VBA MIN and MAX function always returning 0

Tags: vba, range, max, min

Hello I am trying to get the MIN and MAX values from the array and it always returns "0" despite anything. My code:

```
Dim MachineCapacitySmallestArray() As Variant
MachineCapacitySmallestArray = thisworkbook.worksheets(1).range("C25:D25")

SmallestCapacity = Application.Min(MachineCapacitySmallestArray)
```

in range I have natural numbers

I tried formatting those cells to numbers etc. but nothing works. What is the mistake I'm making and how to fix it?

Comment: When you put a Max (or Min) formula in Excel: Does that show the expected value?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Put a formula `=MAX(C25:D25)` in any free cell of that worksheet.

Comment: Yup it still returns 0. I tried formating those cells as text and as numbers and it returns the same result

Comment: Min and Max works on numbers, you have probably text in your cell (that look like a number). Formatting a cell doesn't change it's content, only the way it is displayed.

Comment: After changing the format, being only two cells involved, try double click inside of each of them. The format will take efect only after that...

Comment: But how to do it programmatically in my code? I need it to work without formatting the cells but rather that it would take the array or range as numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments, it seems that your problem is your data, you have likely strings in your cell, not numbers (maybe somehow imported?)

As already mentioned, changing the cell format doesn't change the content of a cell, it just defines how to *display* data. The number `3.14` can be displayed as 3, as 3.140000, as 00003.14 or as 3.14E+00, nothing changes it's value. However, a String `'3.14` is a combination of the characters `3`, `.`, `1` and `4` and has nothing to do with a number. Setting a cell format *after* the value is in the cell will not convert it to a number.

If you read your data into VBA, VBA will get the exact values from Excel and in your case, you will have to convert it into numbers manually, for example with the following routine. The `On Error Resume Next` will prevent a type mismatch if a cell doesn't contain something that can be converted into a number.

```
Sub ArrToNumber(ByRef arr)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            On Error Resume Next
            arr(i, j) = CDbl(arr(i, j))
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Now just add a call to this routine to your code. If you want to have the numbers also in Excel, remove the comment sign from the last statement.

```
Dim MachineCapacitySmallestArray() As Variant
MachineCapacitySmallestArray = thisworkbook.worksheets(1).range("C25:D25")
ArrToNumber MachineCapacitySmallestArray 
SmallestCapacity = Application.Min(MachineCapacitySmallestArray)
' thisworkbook.worksheets(1).range("C25:D25") = MachineCapacitySmallestArray
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yes. Organize your work so that numbers are entered/imported as numbers so that no conversion is needed.

Comment: A non-VBA way would be to type the number 1 into a blank cell and copy it, then highlight your numbers and use Paste Special and select Multiply.  This will perform a calculation on your text and force Excel to recognise them as numbers.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant maybe there's a way to write something like "|CInt(array(i))"